# If $f,g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ are distinct linear functions which map $[-1,1]$ onto $[0,2]$ and $h:\Bbb R\setminus\{-1,0,1\}\to\Bbb R$ defined by $h=f/g$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Given  two distinct linear functions $f$ and $g$ defined on $\mathbb R$ such that they map $[-1,1]$ onto $[0,2]$ and $h:\mathbb R\backslash \{-1,0,1\} \to \mathbb R$ defined by $h(x)=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$, show that 
$$
\left\lvert \,h\big(h\left(x\right)\big)+h\left(h\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)\,\right\rvert > 2
$$

**Attempts**: 
Linear are the functions of the form $ax+by+c=0$.
Between $[-1,1]$ to $[0,2]$ since they are onto they must be a strictly increasing/decreasing.

I was not able to make an conclusions, also tried graphical approach.

Comment: What did you come up with for your two linear functions? Did you figure out what forms $h(x)$ can take? What exactly do you mean by "graphical approach"? What did it reveal?

Comment: I suggest to change the title and see how I formatted mathematical symbols in your question (click on  `edit )

Comment: by linear, you mean polynomial of degree less or equal $1$, right?

Comment: @user251257 yupe

Comment: @Elaqqad thankyou

Comment: $ax+by+c=0$ is the _equation_ for a line in the plane. A linear _function_ has the shape $f(x)=ax+b$, where $a$ and $b$ are constants.

Comment: you can state $f$ and $g$ explicitly. what do you get?

Comment: @CameronBuie i got like a really huge in terms of constants a1 ,b1 a2, b2 ....

Comment: @HenningMakholm thanks for the correction but still i get a huge equation (after applying boundary values -1,1 ) interms of constants of the assumed linear equations f &g like a1,a2,b1,b2

Comment: @SujithZis: You must be doing something wrong, then, but since you're not showing what you _are_ doing, it is impossible to tell you what is wrong about it. Note that there are exactly _two_ linear functions that map $[-1,1]$ surjectively to $[0,2]$; and since $f$ and $g$ are specified to be _distinct_, there are just two possibilities for which function $h$ can be.

Comment: You shouldn't get any huge constants. Something must have gone wrong, but as @Henning said, without seeing what you did, it's impossible to say what.

Comment: @user251257: You should be getting $2$ only at $x=\pm 1$, which are explicitly excluded from the domain of $h$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, sign error :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To proof your inequality :
First determinate $f$ and $g$ for that, you know that either $f$ will be increasing and $g$ will be decreasing or $g$ will be increasing and $f$ will be decreasing, so we can suppose that $f$ is increasing and $g$ is decreasing, so 
we have the system :
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l} f(-1)=-a+b=0 \\
f(1)=a+b=2 \\
g(-1)=-c+d=2 \\
g(1)=c+d=0\\ \end{array}\right.
$$
Where $f(x)=ax+b$ and $g(x)=cx+d$
So $f(x)=x+1$ and $g(x)=-x+1$ so finally :
$$
h(x)=\frac{x+1}{-x+1}
$$
so $h(h(x))= \frac{-1}{x}$ and $h(h(\frac{1}{x}))=-x$.

we need now to proof that for all $a\in\mathbb{R}-\{0,1,-1\}$ 
$$
\left|a+\frac{1}{a}\right|> 2 
$$
in fact 
$$
\left(a+\frac{1}{a}\right)^2=a^2+2+\frac{1}{a^2}> 2+2=4
$$
because $(a-\frac{1}{a})^2> 0 \implies a^2+\frac{1}{a^2}> 2$
So 
$$
\left|h(h(x))+h(h(1/x))\right|=\left|x+\frac{1}{x}\right|> 2
$$
If now we suppose now that $g$ will be increasing and $f$ will be decreasing so we find $h'(x)=h(\frac{1}{x})$ and all calculation will be true.